# Is there a brief way to say `if not var` in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Before I was using python. And I started learning javascript today.

It seems in javascript, both `if ("")`, `if (null)`, `if (0)`, `if (false)` won't trigger the statements after if condition.

So, is there some thing like `if not var` in javascript, so that when a variable's value is among `null, false, 0, ""` the if condition evaluates to true?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: Is this a question about what constitutes truthy/falsey in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple check:

```
if (!someVariable){
    /* the variable has falsy value (null, false, undefined, 0, "0" etc.) */
    /* Variables that are not defined are with undefined type */
}
```

However, if you write something in the `if statement` the completely doesn't exists like `iDontExistAndImNeverEvenMentionedInThisOrInAAboveScope` you check it with:

```
if (typeof someVar == 'undefined') { /* Some code here*/ }
```